# Plot function, differing lengths

Tags: r, plot, neural-network

I am trying to plot using plot() to show the actual vs predicted but I keep getting an Error of x and y lengths differing but I don't know how to fix this error. I am very new to R, I don't quite understand how to correct this. The length of models_predictions_unnorm is showing as 6 whereas currencyDelay_test[4] says length of 4. But printing currencyDelay_test[4], you see this is not the case.

```
library(neuralnet)
library(grid)
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(gridExtra)
library(neuralnet)

normalize <- function(x){
  return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min (x)))
}


data <-
  structure(
    list(
      `USD/EUR` = c(
        1.373,
        1.386,
        1.3768,
        1.3718,
        1.3774,
        1.3672,
        1.3872,
        1.3932,
        1.3911,
        1.3838,
        1.4171,
        1.4164,
        1.3947,
        1.3675,
        1.3801,
        1.3744,
        1.3759,
        1.3743,
        1.3787,
        1.3595,
        1.3599,
        1.3624,
        1.3523,
        1.3506,
        1.3521
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-25L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

#Time delayed data
currencyDelay <- embed(data[[1]], 4)[, 4:1]

currencyNorm <- embed(normalize(data[[1]]), 4)[, 4:1]
currencyNorm
currencyNorm <- as.data.frame(currencyNorm)

train <- currencyNorm[1:16,]
test <- currencyNorm[17:22,]

set.seed(12345)

currency_model <- neuralnet(V4 ~ ., hidden = 12, data = train, act.fct = "logistic")
#plot(currency_model)

model_results <- compute(currency_model, test)
predicted_result <- model_results$net.result

#RMSE here still in 1x4 format
currencyDelay_train <- currencyDelay[1:16,]
currencyDelay_test <- currencyDelay[17:22,]

#Find min and max
cur_min <- min(currencyDelay_train[,4])
cur_max <- max(currencyDelay_train[,4])
currencyDelay_train[,4]

#reversed normalizatrion
unnormalize <- function(x, min, max){
  return ((max-min)*x + min)
}

#Unormalize the predictions
models_predictions_unnorm <- unnormalize(predicted_result, cur_min, cur_max)

--- PLOT ---
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(currencyDelay_test[4], models_predictions_unnorm,col='red',main='Real vs predicted NN',pch=18,cex=0.7)
abline(0,1,lwd=2)
legend('bottomright',legend='NN', pch=18,col='red', bty='n')
```

Comment: Is all code above really needed in a **minimal example** of your problem?

Comment: I think so, since the neural net prediction needs to be correctly carried out to plot at the end. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `currencyDelay_test` is a matrix. With `currencyDelay_test[4]` you only get a single element from that matrix (the foruth one of course) which corresponds to the first row and fourth column. If you want to select the fourth column or row wirte `currencyDelay_test[, 4]` or `currencyDelay_test[4,]`, respectively. Please note that also with a dataframe you would get an error eventhough you'd select indeed the fourth column with `currencyDelay_test[4]`. However, with single brackets you do not drop the surrounding dataframe so you would try to plot a dataframe with one column against a vector which wouldn't make sense. For a data frame you also have to write `currencyDelay_test[, 4]` or alternatively use double brackets to drop the surrounding structure `currencyDelay_test[[4]]`.